# Remove all emails in a list excluding gmails

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to filter an emailList to print only the gmails. The list contains several emails separated by comma, for each person. I want to retrieve each persons gmail while keeping the order of corresponding names.

```
class engineerInfo:
firstName = ""
lastName = ""
email = ""
title = ""

engineers = []

for col in rows:
    e = engineerInfo()
    e.firstName = col[0]
    e.lastName = col[1]
    e.email = col[2]
    e.title = col[3]
    engineers.append(e)

while True:
    print("1- Print gmails of software engineers")
    choice = int(input("Choose from the menu:"))

if choice == 1:
    emailList = []
    for i in engineers:
        if i.email not in emailList:
            emailList.append(i.email)

    gmailList = []
    for i in emailList:
        if i != 'gmail.com':
            continue
        else:
            gmailList.append(i)    
    print(gmailList)
```

Comment: Python is space sensitive. Please indent your code so that it appears here as it does in your editor.

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem. At least one of the tags you added (gmail), is not correct according to the usage guidelines for the tag. This is a text-processing question. It really has nothing to do with email or gmail.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: thanks for the comment. After some afterthought I decided that we indeed better remove the [tag:gmail] tag.

Answer (score 5):

The check should be `.endswith('@gmail.com')`. However email adresses are *case insensitive* like (kudos to [@kwhicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043448/remove-all-emails-in-a-list-excluding-gmails/45043513?noredirect=1#comment77061670_45043513)):

```
gmailList = []
for i in emailList:
    if i.lower().endswith('@gmail.com'):
        gmailList.append(i)
print(gmailList)
```

But you better use *list comprehension* for this (replacing the *entire* `for` loop):

```
gmailList = [i for i in emailList if i.lower().endswith('@gmail.com')]
```

Comment: `print` outside the loop?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: fixed =).

Comment: Nice. I also closed the missing backtick for you.

Comment: Probably safest to use `i.lower().endswith('@gmail.com')` since domain names of email addresses are case insensitive (RFC 1035, section 3.1).